# checksum of a hex string in objective c

Tags: objective-c, checksum

A sample of the data is:

```
de 55 7a ff 41 4e 3b 
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .
```

.

the sum of the first six numbers (in hex) is `33b` and the "checksum" number is `3b`, as the last 2 characters of the sum.

What's the name of this check sum?

How can i make it in Objective C?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, you can see my question : http://stackoverflow.com/users/617801/zuzoovn?tab=questions   Some question dont have accepted answers because nobody have the right answer or dont have the solution. Sorry about that

Comment: I'm not talking about questions with no accepted answers; to my mind (which is purely personal, of course) if someone answers your question and it helps you in any way then you should upvote them.

Comment: (+1) because you help me know this thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Firstly, i must convert hex to NSData.
After that, convert NSData to NSMutableArray.
With NSMutableArray i can calculate the sum of six number.

Comment: I think you don't have to do two conversions if you have a Byte array. All you need to do is to add all bytes together, and get the last byte of the sum.

Comment: how can i  add all bytes together ?

Answer (score 1):

To get checksum of a hex string is really straight forward, most of the time, we are just overthinking it.

If you have a NSMutableData and want to get checksum of it, please check my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639442/how-to-calculate-binary-checksum/19778081?noredirect=1#comment29403933_19778081)

If you have a Byte Array:

For example:

```
Byte receivedHex[7] = {0xde, 0x55, 0x7a, 0xff, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x3b};
```

It's even simpler:

```
Byte checksum;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    checksum += receivedHex[i];
    checksum = checksum&0xff;
}
```